# How I can Pass the variable from the component to the Provider?

Tags: angular, typescript, ionic-framework, ionic2, ionic3

When a user does log in I male post method request with email and password as I will show later. this request return response with API Key to authorize that this user still log in and when to make any API call I must send this API key in the header.

My problem is that when saving that API key in a variable I can't pass it to another provider to make API request to get user info. You know that I must append this API key in this request. How I can Pass the variable from the component to the Provider?

My login Request :

```
 let userKey = 'userkey';

 @Component({
  selector: 'page-login',
  templateUrl: 'login.html',
  providers: [UserProvider] // ADD HERE -> Also add in App.module.ts

 })


export class LoginPage {

  loading: any;
  loginData = { UserEmail:'', Password:'' };
  responseData : any;
  data: any;



  constructor(private UserProvider : UserProvider,public navCtrl: 
   NavController, public authService: UserProvider, public loadingCtrl: 
   LoadingController,public http: Http, private toastCtrl: ToastController) 
 {


 }



login(){

 this.authService.postData(this.loginData,'Login').then((result) => {

 this.responseData = result;
 console.log(this.responseData);
 let userKey = this.responseData.ApiKey
 console.log(userKey);

 localStorage.setItem('loginData', JSON.stringify(this.responseData));
 this.navCtrl.push(DashboardPage)
 console.log(this.loginData)

  }, (err) => {
   // Error log

 });
}
```

Comment: you are storing the login response to localstorage. Then you have all the info like api key there. Just access the localstorage variable and gegt the api key

Comment: I want to save it in variable

Comment: You will have to make a singleton service : https://angular.io/guide/singleton-services .

Or you can save the token into localStorage and retrieve it as needed.

Comment: Your response object would be large. I would save only the token on its own. Not the entire object stringified.

Comment: `AuthService#postData` seems a bit to generic. I would suggest implementing *AuthService* as a singleton with an `#login` method that handles storing the key. Looks like all the above *login* method actually needs is the redirect on success.

Comment: thank you, I did it by store data at localStorage